# Getting Combobox Item Index of pre-loaded multi-column combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

How to get index of item present in combobox(**multi-column combobox**) from the column/item value?

I have tried
**combobox.Items.IndexOf()**
but it is returning -1 though item **is present** with value I am searching for

Comment: I have DataGrid. When user clicks on row, I am fetching the first column's value in string variable, following that window gets opened having combobox. And I want to set its item based on the string variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

`combobox.SelectedIndex` should do the job

To add an item to the combobox:

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
cbi.Width = 50;
cbi.Height = 15;
cbi.Content = "test";
combobox.Items.Add(cbi);
```

Comment: no I just want to select item and set to a selected item in combobox when window gets loaded

Comment: @ManishSant try to state more clearly in your question what you have right now, what goes wrong and what you want to achieve. Maybe consider reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't want to add new value. I gave provided explanation in comment do check.